# What's the output of 'd = {0, 1, 2} for x in d: print(d.add(x)) .And why?

Tags: python, python-3.7

The Python code is:

```
d = {0, 1, 2}
for x in d:
    print(d.add(x))
```

What is the output, and why?

Comment: You can probably find out the first part by running it! This is also important for making an attempt at the second part.

Comment: Adding an existing item to a set will not modify it.

Comment: Also if the set was modified at all during iteration, there would be an error: `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`.

Comment: I think you should realy try to figure out such things yourself. There are tutorials on the web where you have python interpreters online in which you can try out things, so you don't even have to install python on your machine to try things out.. Btw. I think the output does not change whether the element already is in the set or not, just the error doesn't occur, but if you add elements to another set than the one you are iterating over, you can try what happens...

Answer (score 0):

The output is just

```
None
None
None
```

This is because `d.add(x)` adds `x` to the set and returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand this step by step

(1) d is a set of elements{0,1,2}

(2)Set is a data structure which has only unique values

Loop:

(3)for x in d:

print(d.add(x))

this will take each element from the set and add it to self (d.add(x))

AND it returns nothing.

(4)You will get the output three times None because the loop will run three times

As it is a set adding elements to itself will return the original set(It will discard the duplicate entries)